# Oracle - Finding the NEXT largest number

Tags: oracle, sorting, highest

Say I have a list of dates & prices:

```
20170322    109.89
20170321    107.02
20170320    109.25
20170317    108.44
20170316    108.53
20170315    107.94
20170314    106.83
20170313    110.02
20170310    107.31
20170309    107.54
20170308    107.67
20170307    108.98
```

What I need is, from the most recent date: 20170322 (109.89), what is the FIRST date / price value that is HIGHER than the original value, which is 20170313 (110.02).   Note these are in DESC order of the date

Been at this ALL day.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: So: The "original" value (price) of 108.98, the FIRST date when the price was HIGHER was 20170313, when the price was 110.02. We probably must assume that 20170307 is the first date in the entire table (otherwise what makes it special?) What is completely unclear is what you mean by *from the most recent date* - didn't you say (and showed by example) that you start from the oldest date, and you want the FIRST date when the price was higher than the original? What role does the *most recent* date play in all of this? Also, what do you want to see if the price never became HIGHER than original?

Comment: What version of Oracle do you have? Run `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` to find out. In Oracle 12.1 and above, there is a very simple solution with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are called DT and PRICE, and assuming there is only one "thing" whose price you monitor (otherwise you would need a GROUP BY clause):

```
select min(dt) as dt, min(price) keep (dense_rank first order by dt) as price
from   your_table
where  price > ( select min(price) keep (dense_rank first order by dt)
                 from   your_table
               )
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Comment: This is VERY good.   Not quite sure I understand how the DENSE_RANK is working......but I appreciate this quick help!

Comment: @LandonStatis - that is why I added a link to the Oracle documentation, where you can find an explanation, the syntax, and examples. If you are not used to read Oracle documentation, get in the habit of doing it; it's a little scary at first, but it has immense benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause (requires Oracle 12 and above).

I created the test data in a WITH clause. That is NOT PART OF THE SOLUTION; the SQL query begins after the WITH clause, at `SELECT TICKER, ....`

The question mark in the reluctant match in the PATTERN trips the JDBC driver, so this query can't be run from SQL Developer; it needs to be run in SQL*Plus or similar front-end. (The workaround is to change `b*?` to `b*` and to add to the DEFINE clause: `b as b.price <= a.price`.)

To illustrate more of the flexibility of `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, I assumed there may be several "tickers", each with its inception date (earliest date with a price), and the query looks for the first occurrence of a price higher than the original one, per ticker.

```
with
     test_data ( ticker, dt, price ) as (
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170322', 'yyyymmdd'), 109.89 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170321', 'yyyymmdd'), 107.02 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170320', 'yyyymmdd'), 109.25 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170317', 'yyyymmdd'), 108.44 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170316', 'yyyymmdd'), 108.53 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170315', 'yyyymmdd'), 107.94 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170314', 'yyyymmdd'), 106.83 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170313', 'yyyymmdd'), 110.02 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170310', 'yyyymmdd'), 107.31 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170309', 'yyyymmdd'), 107.54 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170308', 'yyyymmdd'), 107.67 from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', to_date('20170307', 'yyyymmdd'), 108.98 from dual
     )
select ticker, dt, price
from   test_data
match_recognize (
  partition by ticker
  order     by dt
  measures  c.dt as dt, c.price as price
  one row per match
  pattern   ( ^ a b*? c )
  define    c as c.price > a.price
)
;

TICKER  DT            PRICE
------  ----------  -------
XYZ     2017-03-13   110.02

1 row selected.
```